# 9patch drawable 1px black line visible & content positioning

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got following 9patch, which I got thanks to nice people who answered my previous question:
[image]

I use it for background in relative layout and TextView and got following.
Thats for RelativeLayout:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android: background="@drawable/cap_stack">
```

[image]

And for TextView:

```
<TextView
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="22dp"
       android:background="@drawable/cap_stack"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

[image]

As you can see, I got 1px wide line visible in both cases. And in case of TextView text is not placed in the center vertical. How can I fix it(is it drawable problem or xml)? Will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have a solid border all the way around. The top and left borders define the stretch areas (you only need one pixel on the top for stretching, and you want JUST the gradient to stretch on the vertical axis). The bottom and right borders define the content area, so you want to leave some padding as well. The four corner pixels should never be filled.

Try this one:

[image]

or this one:

[image]

Comment: Thanx, there's no black line now, but text inside textview is still posisioned on the bottom. Do I need to create another 9patch that is thiner for it?

Comment: Probably so. It's weird with gradients, because if you make it too small, if you have to make it larger, the gradient isn't going to be as high quality. This might be better to just do as a gradient drawable for the background, but I've edited in another one for you to try as well. Try taking off the padding on the TextView as well, that's going to throw off your centering, but that might be your intention.

Answer (score 1):

try this for your textview, the problem is your layout_height  You are wanting the textSize attribute instead. Also, notice I used the SP unit instead of DP as that is what the docs recommend for text size values.  I hope this helps!

```
<TextView
   android:paddingTop="5dp"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:textSize="22sp"
   android:background="@drawable/cap_stack"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you named your image as `cap_stack.9.png`? It seems android is not processing it as 9patch.

Comment: Image is streched horizontally, so it seems to me that android 'knows' that it's 9patch.

Comment: Android can stretch images even if they are not 9patch.

Answer (score 0):

android:gravity="center_vertical" works with LinearLayout Only , Use Layout_centerVertical=true for relativeLayout .

and that lines on border seems part of your image , not seeing any other possibility //////so rechecking  image once might be helpful .

Comment: I want text in text view to be positioned like "center_vertical".